# Changing button style on POST AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, post

I have a contact form, and on submit, it sends a POST to a backend file:

```
<div class="field text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="submit form-btn" ng-disabled="contactForm.$invalid">Send</button>
</div>
```

The POST:

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '/php/contact.php',
            data    : $.param($scope.contactData),  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
}
```

I wanted to change the color and text of my button when the function a successful POST and when it has an error. My guess is that in the success and error Callback functions I have to update the DOM, but how would I do that? Or is there a better/simpler way?

Comment: Do you want to do after success or when the function called?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle. ngStyle enables you to pass styling values to the View from your Controller.

Comment: You can use jQuery in the success or error function as $('.field button').css('background-color', 'red');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) to change the style of a DOM element in the controller.

HTML:

```
<div class="field text-center">
    <button ng-style="httpCall" type="submit" class="submit form-btn" ng-disabled="contactForm.$invalid">{{httpCallText}}</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : '/php/contact.php',
        data    : $.param($scope.contactData),  // pass in data as strings
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var buttonColor = "green";
        $scope.httpCallText = "Success";
        $scope.httpCall = {
          'background-color': buttonColor
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        var buttonColor = "red";
        $scope.httpCallText = "Error";
        $scope.httpCall = {
          'background-color': buttonColor
        }
    });
}
```

If you have any question about this answer, let me know!